# Simplex Cycling won't happen if degree of degeneracy is 1

Tags: convex-optimization, linear-programming, simplex

Show that in the simplex method cycling won’t happen if the degree of degeneracy is no more than 1, no matter what pivoting rule is used.

Can anyone help me prove this?

Comment: Please provide more context.  What have you tried to do already?  A hint: Is it possible for the simplex method to move from basis B1 to basis B2 in one iteration and then back to basis B1 in the next iteration?

Comment: No this is not possible.

Comment: Can you apply that fact to your problem?

Comment: This can be useful when at most two bases are associated with each degree one degenerate point. This is possible when n-m = 1 (n: # of variables, m: # of constraints) or equivalently having sequence of bases B_0, B_1, B_0 is impossible . In this case argument above works. for arbitrary n-m = k then Simplex can loop through at most k+1 bases: B_0, B_1, ...., B_k, B_(k+1), B_0.

Comment: What do you know about variables leaving and entering the basis? Can a variable that enters the basis in one iteration leave in the next iteration?  Can a variable that leaves the basis in one iteration reenter in the next iteration?

Comment: The variable which just exited cannot reenter immediately. A variable which just entered can exit immediately.